# Write rules in jquery-validation for Rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-validation-engine

I have a form in HTML code

```
<form>
  <input placeholder="Your name" class="string required" type="text" name="service_order[your_name]" id="service_order_your_name" aria-required="true">
  <input placeholder="Your email" class="string email optional" type="email" name="service_order[email]" id="service_order_email">
</form>
```

the code is generate by Simpleform in Rails

```
= simple_form_for(@service_order) do |f|
  = f.input :your_name
  = f.input :email
```

And I use jquery validation to check user input.
To define the rules in javascript, we simple write something similar to:

```
$("#new_service_order").validate(
    rules:
      your_name:
        minlength: 2
  )
```

My problem is the field is **service_order[st]**, not just **st** like the example. How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [reference docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-fields-with-complex-names-(brackets-dots)), you need to quote the names as in

```
$("#new_service_order").validate({
  rules: {
    'service_order[your_name]': {
      minlength: 20
     },
    'service_order[email]': {
      email: true
    }
  }
});
```

Also, please note that you need to fix the object literal passed to the validate function.